# How do I pull date criteria from multiple columns from ONE table?

Tags: sql, date, select, sql-server-2012

I've been working with SQL for a little time so fairly new but have been catching on very quick. I have this very intense query I need to create for a report - I have this in excel and use IF statements and works perfectly.

Here's what I have and need:
I have one table with multiple columns containing dates.

One 'Raving Fan Name' could have more than one date. These are the possibilities / example:

```
RavingFan ID 1 = FU Date + Testimonial Date + Bonus Date
RavingFan ID 2 = Referral Date + Signed Date
RavingFan ID 3 = Testimonial Date
```

I need to pull data from each column containing  a date filter (of a rolling 6 months) I've read multiple select select statements. This is what I have but it tells me I need a EXISTS - hopefully someone can help!!

```
SELECT 

(SELECT 
rf.Raving_Fan_ID,
rf.Raving_Fan_Name,
cr.Contact_Role_Name,
emp.Emp_Name,
rf.FU_Detail,
rf.FU_Date,
rf.FU_Point,
rf.Bonus_Date,
rf.Bonus_Point

FROM Raving_Fans AS rf

LEFT JOIN Employees AS emp ON rf.Emp_ID = emp.Emp_ID
LEFT JOIN Contact_Role AS cr ON rf.Contact_Role_ID = cr.Contact_Role_ID

WHERE rf.FU_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-181,getdate()) AND DATEADD(day,0,getdate()) 
)

(SELECT 
rf.Raving_Fan_ID,
rf.Raving_Fan_Name,
cr.Contact_Role_Name,
emp.Emp_Name,
rf.Test_Detail,
rf.Test_Date,
rf.Test_Point,
rf.Bonus_Date,
rf.Bonus_Point

FROM Raving_Fans AS rf

LEFT JOIN Employees AS emp ON rf.Emp_ID = emp.Emp_ID
LEFT JOIN Contact_Role AS cr ON rf.Contact_Role_ID = cr.Contact_Role_ID

WHERE  rf.Test_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-181,getdate()) AND DATEADD(day,0,getdate()) 
)

(SELECT 
rf.Raving_Fan_ID,
rf.Raving_Fan_Name,
cr.Contact_Role_Name,
emp.Emp_Name,
rf.Ref_Detail,
rf.Ref_Date,
rf.Ref_Point,
rf.Signed_Date,
rf.Signed_Point,
rf.Bonus_Date,
rf.Bonus_Point

FROM Raving_Fans AS rf

LEFT JOIN Employees AS emp ON rf.Emp_ID = emp.Emp_ID
LEFT JOIN Contact_Role AS cr ON rf.Contact_Role_ID = cr.Contact_Role_ID

WHERE rf.Ref_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-181,getdate()) AND DATEADD(day,0,getdate())
)
```

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this. Is there an easier way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'll see what I can come up with. Was just hoping if someone could tell me how to achieve getting data from multiple columns without duplicating the PK ID. From additional research I have done - I'm assuming this might entail WITH CTE query

Comment: I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is done, If you want to pull certain criteria from multiple columns.

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT  
    rf.Raving_Fan_ID,
    rf.Raving_Fan_Name AS "Raving Fan",
    cr.Contact_Role_Name AS "Contact Type",
    emp.Emp_Name AS "TCS Employee",

    rf.FU_Detail AS "Follow Ups",
    CASE WHEN rf.FU_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.FU_Date ELSE NULL END AS "FU Date",
    CASE WHEN rf.FU_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.FU_Point ELSE NULL END AS "FU Point",

    rf.Test_Detail AS "Testimonials",
    CASE WHEN rf.Test_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.Test_Date ELSE NULL END AS "Test Date",
    CASE WHEN rf.Test_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.Test_Point ELSE NULL END AS "Test Point",

    rf.Ref_Detail AS "Referrals",
    CASE WHEN rf.Ref_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.Ref_Date ELSE NULL END AS "Ref Date",
    CASE WHEN rf.Ref_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.Ref_Point ELSE NULL END AS "Ref Point",
    CASE WHEN rf.Signed_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.Signed_Date ELSE NULL END AS "Signed Date",
    CASE WHEN rf.Signed_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.Signed_Point ELSE NULL END AS "Signed Point",
    CASE WHEN rf.Bonus_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.Bonus_Date ELSE NULL END AS "Bonus Date",
    CASE WHEN rf.Bonus_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.Bonus_Point ELSE NULL END AS "Bonus Point",

    (CASE WHEN rf.Ref_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.Ref_Point ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN rf.Signed_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.Signed_Point ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN rf.FU_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE())   THEN rf.FU_Point ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE WHEN rf.Test_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.Test_Point ELSE 0 END + 
     CASE WHEN rf.Bonus_Date BETWEEN CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) THEN rf.Bonus_Point ELSE 0 END) AS "Total Points"

FROM [dbo].[Raving_Fans] AS rf
    LEFT JOIN Employees AS emp ON rf.Emp_ID = emp.Emp_ID
    LEFT JOIN Contact_Role AS cr ON rf.Contact_Role_ID = cr.Contact_Role_ID

WHERE (rf.FU_Date between CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
OR (rf.Test_Date between CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
OR (rf.Ref_Date between CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
OR (rf.Signed_Date between CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
OR (rf.Bonus_Date between CONVERT(date,DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())) and CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
AND(emp.Emp_Name LIKE '%' +@Emp_Name+ '%' OR @Emp_Name IS NULL)

ORDER BY emp.Emp_Name ASC;
```

Comment: I follow what you are saying, but a little explanation to accompany such a wad of code would make your answer more useful.